# Adding retweetCount column to dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of tweets and I would like to add a column, "retweetCount" that does not exist. I am using the following:

```
tweets$retweetCount <- tweets %>%
group_by(text) %>%
summarize(count = n())
```

This throws the following error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, retweetCount, value = list(text = c("- 
#WetterOnline Pro by @WetterOnline #Wetter #Berlin,  : 
replacement has 48780 rows, data has 137659
```

It seems that I am unable to calculate the value for "retweetCount" in cases where there were no retweets.

```
head(data): 
id_str <chr>, from_user <chr>, text <chr>, created_at <chr>, time <chr>, 
geo_coordinates <chr>,user_lang <chr>, in_reply_to_user_id_str <chr>, 
in_reply_to_screen_name <chr>,from_user_id_str <chr>, 
in_reply_to_status_id_str <chr>, source <chr>,profile_image_url <chr>, 
user_followers_count <int>, user_friends_count <int>,user_location <chr>, 
status_url <chr>, entities_str <chr>, date <date>

dput(data)
.Names = c("id_str", "from_user", "text", 
"created_at", "time", "geo_coordinates", "user_lang", 
"in_reply_to_user_id_str", 
"in_reply_to_screen_name", "from_user_id_str", "in_reply_to_status_id_str", 
"source", "profile_image_url", "user_followers_count", "user_friends_count", 
"user_location", "status_url", "entities_str", "date", "ehe", 
"eggheads"), row.names = c(NA, -137659L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Could you post your data or a sample of it so w  could help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly (without having seen the data), this should solve your problem.

```
aux <- tweets %>%
  group_by(text) %>%
  summarize(retweetCount = n())

tweets <- inner_join(tweets, aux, by = "text")
```